# What is the mass dimension of scattering amplitudes in string and membrane theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, scattering, dimensional-analysis, branes

It's all in the title: I am interested in the mass dimension (in natural units) of scattering amplitudes in string and membrane theories. For particles in $d=4$, [it seems to be](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/452119/)

$$[ \mathcal{A}^{(n)} ] = 4 - n. \tag{1}$$

Does that hold for strings and higher-dimensional objects? Following the same logic as in the answer from the link above, I would guess that the dimensionality of the amplitude is independent of the kind of object (particles, strings, etc) and the only new dependency would be the target space dimensions. If this is true, I obtain

$$[ \mathcal{A}^{(n)} ] = \frac{d-2}{2} n - d n + 2n + d = d+n - \frac{d n}{2}, \tag{2}$$

which reduces to $(1)$ for $d = 4$. Does that make sense? (I am unsure about the first term, maybe I should set $(d-2)/2$ to $-1$ (the dimensionality of target-space coordinates)? If I do so it doesn't reduce to $(1)$ anymore though.)

Comment: Why the downvote? I am happy to edit the question if it is unclear.

Comment: hint: the mass dimension of any scattering amplitude is such that (modulus-squared) S-matrix elements are dimensionless (in order to interpret them as probabilities). usually one strips off kinematic factors and momentum conserving factors in order to define the Lorentz-invariant amplitude, $A_n$. And one often considers scattering in unit spatial volume, because this volume cancels out of observables. These are all true in string theory too. (in this viewpoint, the dimensionality of the full S matrix is also independent of the number of external states, so they must also be dimensionless.)